# Data Structure / Design for Product & Shipping Info

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store some data regarding items, warehouse, and shipping costs

For example my store has some items, and different warehouses stock them, although not necessarily all of items. Then each warehouse may have different costs of shipping the item, depending on how close they are to the destination.

So as an example

```
warehouse1 : item1, item3, item 5
warehouse2 : item1, item2
warehouse3 : item1, item3, item 4

so if the order consists of (item 1, item 2, item 3) 
it can be fulfilled by either warehouse1 + warehouse2, or warehouse3 + warehouse2. 
in this case it should choose whichever is cheaper
```

In this case, I want to minimize the # of warehouses that are used to fulfill an order, as well as minimize the cost. Orders can have multiple items of different types, but they will all go to the same destination.

I was thinking to store a list of all the products as something like

```
class Item{
   double price;
   List<Integer> warehouses; //id of all the warehouses that carry this item
}
```

However it seems expensive to calculate the optimal warehouses to fulfill the order. Right now when an order comes in, I lookup all the items from a hashtable, to get the list of all the warehouses for each item.

Then I can create a Set of all the possible shipment solutions and then pick the min cost solution from that. This is very slow since I have to generate all the possible shipping combinations. I have a hunch there is a better way to do this but can't seem to come up with anything, is there something I am missing?

Comment: To the customer, can it be one package or multiple separate packages?

Comment: Customer can receive multiple package, the main goal is to minimize the shipping costs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is essentially the textbook definition of the [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Each of the warehouses corresponds to a subset, and the universe would correspond to the order that you need to satisfy. This is unfortunately NP-complete and known algorithms will have exponential complexity.

You may be able to get good heuristics results depending upon other constraints in your problem (or depending on your error tolerance, there are polynomial approximations in the same link).

Answer (score 1):

I have not designed such solution in past but this is the most likely way, I will go about it as outlined below.

First I will build a base case then I will improve upon it instead of doing - **generate all the possible shipping combinations** in advance as you have already noticed that It will be slow.

What we are looking here is a fast solution too in addition to cost being optimal and in practical situations, you will have to factor in - **Customer Satisfaction** too.

Your target is to generate a `Shipment` which is basically a `Map<Warehouse,List<Item>>` for an order.

You need another table that tells you about the cost of a shipment - `Map<Cost,Shipment>`.

**Base-Case**

**Step#1.** Prepare list of all warehouses in destination distance ordered i.e. sort warehouses increasing order of distance from warehouse

**Step#2.** First identify nearest warehouse to your destination

**Step#3.** Strikeout all items that can be fulfilled from warehouse detected in Step # 2

**Step#4.** Repeat Step # 2 and Step # 3 for remaining items, ignoring already looked warehouses

**Step#5.** Stop if none of items remain.

You will have your base_case shipment after above five steps.

To know if your base case is a **good enough solution**, you should already have a shipment heuristic to tell you approximate allowable cost for a particular destination for the layout of your company's warehouses and the areas that you cover i.e. at this point you should decide if improvements to base case is needed or not.

If improvement is needed, You can create another new shipment by moving items from shorter distance warehouses to longer distance warehouses provided that results in cost savings (of course only for available items in farther warehouses and if number of grouped items increase at farther ware house than shorter one).

Out of five steps, you might also decide to ship the items at **Step#3** above if customer satisfaction weighs in. Its usually considered more customer friendly to deliver partial items quickly than to let him/her wait for bulky packages.

Also, I don't think you need any specific data structures other than look - up tables.

As I have already said, I have not implemented anything as such for real and this is just my opinion.

Hope it helps !!